# leaflet geojson style function feature only colors 1 geojson feature

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I need to style every feature differently that I pull from a geojson file.  However this anonymous style function only changes the style on the first feature it comes across and stops. I am new to leaflet.  Have seen several demos but cant find a reason why this anonymous style function only changes the style of the first feature and not the rest? The getTableData function returns a color from table generated on page load.

feature Example

```
var countyData = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "ENTITYYR": 2010.0, "NAME": "COUNTY1", "FIPS": 25.0, "FIPS_STR": "49025", "COLOR4": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ Long List Of Coordinates here ] ] } }
, etc

    geojson = L.geoJson(countyData, {
        style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.NAME) {
        case 'COUNTY1': return {color: '#' + getTableData(feature.properties.NAME)};
        break;
        case 'COUNTY2': return {color: '#' + getTableData(feature.properties.NAME)};
        break;
        case 'COUNTY3': return {color: '#' + getTableData(feature.properties.NAME)};
        break;
        case 'COUNTY4': return {color: '#' + getTableData(feature.properties.NAME)};
        break;
        case 'COUNTY5': return {color: '#' + getTableData(feature.properties.NAME)};
        break;
    }
        },
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Missing some code here, what does the `getTableData` method do? Could you add that? What is contained within `feature.properties.NAME`? Perhaps you can post an example of a feature?

Comment: @iH8 Updated Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the other functions called had an error

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to match `COUNTRY1` with `country1`, that won't work. Javascript switch is casesensitive.

Comment: No Typo  I need to keep my postings anonymous so when changing those names to generic info I did not maintain the naming convention